# What does MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey really do?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sqldataadapter

The default value of `SqlDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction` is `MissingSchemaAction.Add`, but when I specify the `AddWithKey` I can't understand what it really do ?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "mytable");
```

When the use of `AddWithKey` can be useful ?

Comment: It seems that it does something else than explained in the documentation. If I fill a dataset using MissingSchemaAction.Add (the default) and I look at the MaxLength for string columns (System.Data.DataColumn) it returns -1. With MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey it returns the database definition for the column!! I compared it with the SQL and Oracle drivers and both do the same. This is confusing as there is no information at all about this behavior :-(

Comment: @Raul I have the exact contrary on my test machine: Add will return correct MaxLength values, whereas AddWithKey will return -1s. Did you ever find out the reason, or better yet a way around this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.missingschemaaction(v=vs.110).aspx) says, it "adds the necessary columns and primary key information to complete the schema"

It states the primary function of `AddWithKey` as: "This ensures that incoming records that match existing records are updated instead of appended."

A little reverse engineering reveals the following:

When you invoke `DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, string)` it executes the `DbCommand.ExecuteReader` with `CommandBehavior` set to `SequentialAccess`

If you specify `MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;` the `CommandBehavior.KeyInfo` is added to the behavior.

This causes the `DbCommand.ExecuteReader` invoked internally to add the following on top of your query:

```
SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON;
```

Which is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173812.aspx) by Microsoft (as below)

> The browse mode lets you scan the rows in your SQL Server table and
>   update the data in your table one row at a time. To access a SQL
>   Server table in your application in the browse mode, you must use one
>   of the following two options:
>
> The SELECT statement that you use to access the data from your SQL
>   Server table must end with the keywords FOR BROWSE. When you turn on
>   the FOR BROWSE option to use browse mode, temporary tables are
>   created.
>
> You must run the following Transact-SQL statement to turn on the
>   browse mode by using the NO_BROWSETABLE option:
>
> ```
> SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON
> ```
>
> When you turn on the NO_BROWSETABLE option, all the SELECT statements
>   behave as if the FOR BROWSE option is appended to the statements.
>   However, the NO_BROWSETABLE option does not create the temporary
>   tables that the FOR BROWSE option generally uses to send the results
>   to your application.