# GetSchemaTable() does not return the IsKey property

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

-Hello, World!-

I am working on a C# with ASP.NET project and I have run into a snag. The project is to dynamically load metadata and records from tables to edit them without statically defining what tables could be edited. As such I need to get the schema/metadata of different tables.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// initialize the connection
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(metadata.DatabaseString))
{
    // open the connection
    con.Open();

    // initialize a new SqlCommand to get the schema
    SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    // 0 = 1 ensures it's always an empty data set
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + metadata.TableName + " WHERE 0=1;";

    // set to SchemaOnly to improve performance (i think)
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);

    // GetSchemaTable() gets the table's metadata
    DataTable dataTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

    // loops through all the rows of the data table
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        // field names found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks
        metadata.ColumnMetadata.Add(new ColumnWrapper()
        {
            ColumnType = GetTypeFromSql(row.Field<string>("DataTypeName")),
            ColumnRawType = row.Field<string>("DataTypeName"),
            ColumnName = row.Field<string>("ColumnName"),
            ByteSize = row.Field<int>("ColumnSize"),
            IsKey = row.Field<bool?>("IsKey") ?? false
        });
    }
}
```

The issue is the IsKey field is always empty. My SQL Server Table was created using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dtm_LKUP_Role] (
    [DtmRoleId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleName]  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive]  BIT DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DtmRoleId] ASC)
);
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

- Use a different table, same results
- Access `dataTable.Columns["IsKey"]`

No matter where I look I can't find the information I need. Does anyone have any ideas on what could cause this? In case it is relevant, I am using an MDF file and the LocalDB for my database connection rather than a live server.

Comment: Does https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cc1451e-e243-498e-80dc-23b095518cb6/idatareadergetschematable-returns-false-for-a-primary-key-column?forum=adodotnetdataproviders help? Or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641549/what-does-missingschemaaction-addwithkey-really-do)

Answer (score 0):

Houston, we have lift off!

Based on the help from mjwills, I managed to get it working by changing my code to the following:

```
// initialize the connection
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(metadata.DatabaseString))
{
    // open the connection
    con.Open();

    // initialize a new SqlCommand to get the schema. 0 = 1 ensures an empty data set
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + metadata.TableName + " WHERE 0=1", con);

    // GetSchemaTable() gets the table's metadata
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    // tell the adapater to fill in the missing schema
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

    // fill the datatable with the schema
    adapter.FillSchema(dataTable, SchemaType.Mapped);

    // loops through all the rows of the data table
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        // field names found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks
        metadata.ColumnMetadata.Add(new ColumnWrapper()
        {
            ColumnType = column.DataType,
            ColumnName = column.ColumnName,
            ByteSize = column.MaxLength,
            IsKey = dataTable.PrimaryKey.Contains(column)
        });
    }
}
```

I appreciate all the help from those who commented on my original question :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change :

```cs
  // set to SchemaOnly to improve performance (i think)
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
```

to

```cs
  // set to SchemaOnly to improve performance (i think)
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
```

And it should work.

Comment: This post is 5 years old.